# How to inspect/edit a native method in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio

Aim: I want to update keep non null and reuse `mRecordingCanvas`(inside Picture.java)  in `MyCustomView`.
i.e. will not reset null if last time I draw a line from (0,0) to (0,100),
later I call it again using custom method `continueRecording` and draw one more line from (0,100) 
to (100,100),
hence I don't need to draw everything again if I want to add 10-100 more lines into the "same" `mRecordingCanvas`.

I expect to add

```
    @NonNull
    public Canvas continueRecording() {
    return mRecordingCanvas;
    }
```

and remove `mRecordingCanvas = null`; inside

```
    public void endRecording() {
    verifyValid();
    if (mRecordingCanvas != null) {
    mRequiresHwAcceleration = mRecordingCanvas.mHoldsHwBitmap;
    //mRecordingCanvas = null;
    nativeEndRecording(mNativePicture);
    }
    }
```

and remove //   if (mRecordingCanvas != null) {
           // throw new IllegalStateException("Picture already recording, must call #endRecording()");
        //}
and change the variable inside PictureCanvas to (this, bitmap)
inside

```
@NonNull
public Canvas beginRecording(int width, int height) {
    verifyValid();
    if (mRecordingCanvas != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Picture already recording, must call #endRecording()");
    }
    //long ni = nativeBeginRecording(mNativePicture, width, height);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mRecordingCanvas = new PictureCanvas(this, bitmap);
    mRequiresHwAcceleration = false;
    return mRecordingCanvas;
}
```

---

However there are some problems for Picture.java inside package android.graphics;

(1)  Picture.java has a sentence `@UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = 28)` ,
but the `TargetSdk` of my APP want to be `Sdk` = 29, so I may need to make a `MyPicture.java`

(2) when I Copy all things in Picture.java into MyPicture.java and remove 
 `@UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = 28)`.
Some problems occurs as I try to use Android Studio to run debug APP using the mobile (Sdk ver = 28),
the debug log shows that cannot find the native

```
    public class MyCustomView extends View {
       private MyPicture mPicture = new MyPicture();

       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       if (initialTimeMillis == 0) {
        //do sth
        Canvas temp_canvas = 
        mPicture.beginRecording(MainActivity.global_int_widthpx,MainActivity.global_int_heightpx);
        mPicture.endRecording();
        initialTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis;
        return;
        }

        Canvas temp_canvas = mPicture.continueRecording();
                    current_Float_xy[0] = last_Float_xy[0]  +  deltaXY_path1[0]*tempTimeDifferencePercent;
                    current_Float_xy[1] = last_Float_xy[1]  +  deltaXY_path1[1]*tempTimeDifferencePercent;
        temp_canvas.drawLine(last_Float_xy[0],last_Float_xy[1],current_Float_xy[0],current_Float_xy[1], 
        strokePaint);
        mPicture.endRecording();
        mPicture.draw(temp_canvas);
          postInvalidate();
      ｝
    ｝
```

---

The debug log shows

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void 
 com.xxx.yyy.MyPicture.nativeEndRecording(long) (tried Java_com_xxx_yyy_MyPicture_nativeEndRecording and Java_com_xxx_yyy_MyPicture_nativeEndRecording__J)  
        at com.xxx.yyy.MyPicture.nativeEndRecording(Native Method)  
        at com.xxx.yyy.MyPicture.endRecording(MyPicture.java:140)  
        at com.xxx.yyy.MyCustomView.onDraw(MyCustomView.java:385)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20211)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19086)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19077)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19077)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19077)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19077)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19077)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19077)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19939)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)  
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)  
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20214)  
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)  
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19086)  
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)  
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)  
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)  
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3327)  
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3124)  
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2493)  
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)  
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7208)  
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1004)  
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:816)  
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:751)  
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:990)  
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)  
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)  
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)  
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

---

I don't know what "com.xxx.yyy.MyPicture.nativeEndRecording(long) (tried Java_com_xxx_yyy_MyPicture_nativeEndRecording and Java_com_xxx_yyy_MyPicture_nativeEndRecording__J)"
but I think it cannot find the corresponding native code when I use a MyPicture not in original graphic package.

Problem (3) : I want to jump into the native code "nativeEndRecording" to see whether I can know more concrete code behind in the below list by using "Ctrl+left_mouse_click" but I jump back to the same MyPicture.java in another line that use it.
This means I don't know how to inspect, amend and recreate a custom native Method, and inject the Method into the APP...

```
private static native long nativeConstructor(long nativeSrcOr0);
private static native long nativeCreateFromStream(InputStream stream, byte[] storage);
private static native int nativeGetWidth(long nativePicture);
private static native int nativeGetHeight(long nativePicture);
private static native long nativeBeginRecording(long nativeCanvas, int w, int h);
private static native void nativeEndRecording(long nativeCanvas);
private static native void nativeDraw(long nativeCanvas, long nativePicture);
private static native boolean nativeWriteToStream(long nativePicture,
                                                  OutputStream stream, byte[] storage);
private static native void nativeDestructor(long nativePicture);
```

I lose my direction now... what I want to do is just keep previous canvas drawing and repeating to draw more short lines (maybe 60~166 lines with 30-100 px length and 30px width gradually in 1 seconds).
As the APP use 83 Mb graphic memory if I just repeat ondraw ~=166 times.
It likes a snow ball and graphic memory again rapidly for last few hundreds ms when the path becomes much longer and longer with slight increase in length everytime.